# How to rearrange the JSON object that Artoo.js generates?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, sorting, data-structures

I have a very simple file that should scrape a single webpage for some data. After reading around I set myself to artoo, request and cheerio but now I'm stuck. This is the code I have so far.

```
request('http://www.ciclopi.eu/frmLeStazioni.aspx?ID=144', function (error, response, html) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
      var $ = cheerio.load(html);
      artoo.bootstrap(cheerio);

      var scraper = $('span.Stazione, span.TableComune, span.Red').scrape({
        class: 'class', 
        content: 'text'
      });
      console.log(scraper);
   }
});
```

This code resolves into the *scraper* variable as a json object structured like this:

```
[ { class: 'Stazione', content: 'Galleria Gerace' },
{ class: 'TableComune', content: 'Via Carlo Matteucci' },
{ class: 'Red', content: '7 bici libere5 posti disponibili' },
{ class: 'Stazione', content: 'C. Marchesi' },
{ class: 'TableComune', content: 'Via M. Valgimigli' },
{ class: 'Red', content: '2 bici libere10 posti disponibili' },
{ class: 'Stazione', content: 'CNR-Praticelli' },
{ class: 'TableComune', content: 'Via G. Moruzzi' },
{ class: 'Red', content: '7 bici libere7 posti disponibili' } ]
```

What I need is to rearrange the *scraper* object as something like this

```
scraper = [
    {
        "Name": the content for class Stazione,        
        "Address": the content for class TableComune,
        "Bikes": the content for class Red
    },
    {
        "Name": the content for class Stazione,        
        "Address": the content for class TableComune,
        "Bikes": the content for class Red
    }
    ...
]
```

I'm really in the dark here, hopefully I explained myself..

Comment: `myObj` in your post is totally invalid entity, could you specify more precisely what you want in the result?

Comment: That's simply how I want my object to look like in the end, it basically groups "Stazione", "TableComune" and "Red" from the scraper object. They are data for bike sharing stations. I'll try to edit in a better way.

Comment: Your update helped, so I was able to solve your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this kind of mutations I would use [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method.

```
const data = [ 
  { class: 'Stazione', content: 'Galleria Gerace' },
  { class: 'TableComune', content: 'Via Carlo Matteucci' },
  { class: 'Red', content: '7 bici libere5 posti disponibili' },
  { class: 'Stazione', content: 'C. Marchesi' },
  { class: 'TableComune', content: 'Via M. Valgimigli' },
  { class: 'Red', content: '2 bici libere10 posti disponibili' },
  { class: 'Stazione', content: 'CNR-Praticelli' },
  { class: 'TableComune', content: 'Via G. Moruzzi' },
  { class: 'Red', content: '7 bici libere7 posti disponibili' }
];

const result = data.reduce((acc, item) => {
  if (item.class === 'Stazione') {
    acc.push({ 'Name': item.content });
  } else {
    const last = acc[acc.length - 1];
    if (item.class === 'TableComune') {
      last['Address'] = item.content;
    } else { // if (item.class === 'Red')
      last['Bikes'] = item.content;
    }
  }
  return acc;
}, []);
```

Here we are iterating through the initial data array and generating the result array by 2 conditional points:

- if current item is Stazione then we are pushing a new object to the result array; this object will have Name property corresponded to current Stazione content
- otherwise we are updating the last element of the result array: TableComune content will move to Address property, Red content will move to Bikes property.

The procedure will work only in case of strict order of Stazione-TableComune-Red objects in the initial data array.

Comment: That's exactly it! I was stuck understanding how the whole "pushing" into a new object worked and didn't know about the reduce method. Thanks a lot!